# Phpbb3 forum integration with existing site

Tags: session, forum, phpbb3

I am trying to integrate the phpbb forum with my existing site. I have already looked at [these](http://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/phpbb3-cross-site-sessions-integration/) [links](http://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/phpbb3-sessions-integration/), and it doesn't seem to work. I have copied this code

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
define('ROOT_PATH', "/path/to/forums"); 
    if (!defined('IN_PHPBB') || !defined('ROOT_PATH')) {
exit();
}
$phpEx = "php";
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : ROOT_PATH . '/';
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
```

into a loginforum.php file, which I include in every page I want the sessions to be kept. I have done the three steps indicated in the sessions integration section, but when I try to check whether the user is authenticated, it doesn't seem so. Using the same code here:

```
<?php
if ($user->data['user_id'] == ANONYMOUS){
    echo 'Please login!';
}
else{
    echo 'Thanks for logging in, ' . $user->data['username_clean'];
}
?>
```

I only get the "Please login" phrase, even when I login.

I've been over this for hours, I don't understand where the problem is. Shouldn't it work after the three miraculous steps?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if ($user->data['username'] == 'Anonymous')
{
    echo 'Please login!';
}
```

This is the first (and guest) user in the PHPBB database:

```
SELECT  `user_id`, 
    `username`, 
    `username_clean` 
    FROM 
`phpbb_users` WHERE user_id = 1
```

Result:

```
"user_id"   "username"  "username_clean"
"1" "Anonymous" "anonymous"
```

Comment: I highly doubt that. `Anonymous` is most likely a valid name for an existing user.

Comment: You are incorrect. That is PHPBB's guest user. Section 3.5.1: http://www.phpbb.com/support/documentation/3.0/adminguide/acp_users.php, follow that or query the database and you will see the user name is `Anonymous`

Comment: I've edited my answer to show that `Anonymous` is the first user added to a PHPBB install